# Calling a property or member function of a string object inside of a ListView

Tags: asp.net, string, listview

I'm having some trouble calling a property or a method on a databound string object inside of a ListView. See this example:

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="FullInfoListView">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table class="tablestripe" width="100%">
            <asp:Placeholder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceholder" />
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr valign="top" runat="server" Visible='<%# !string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)Eval("Phone")) %>'>
            <td><strong>Phone:</strong></td>
            <td><span runat="server" Visible='<%# ((string)Eval("Phone")).Length == 4 %>'>x</span><%# Eval("Phone") %></td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

This line:

```
<%# ((string)Eval("Phone")).Length == 4 %>'>
```

is what is giving me trouble. If I remove the .Length everything works fine. If I leave it in there my code throws an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." exception on the line where I call the DataBind() method on the ListView in my code behind. This same behavior occurs with .ToLower() as well.

**EDIT**

I think I got this figured out. Thanks for those of you who suggested moving this out to a method in the code behind to help with debugging. The problem was related to a null reference...go figure :) I thought that if the table row wasn't visible that none of the logic inside would get evaluated, but I think due to the fact that it is databound the logic is evaluated anyway. So simply changing the above line to the following fixed the problem:

```
<%# Eval("Phone") != null && ((string)Eval("Phone")).Length == 4 %>'>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would consider using a `Label` instead of a `<span>`. Instead of casting it to `string`, just use the `ToString()` function instead, and wrap the entire expression in parentheses to ensure that it's evaluating as a boolean:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Visible='<%# (Eval("Phone").ToString().Length >= 4) %>' Text="X" />
```

If the above doesn't fix your problem, you can always add a method in the code behind to do this:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Visible='<%# CheckLength(Eval("Phone").ToString()) %>' Text="X" />
```

Code-behind:

```
public bool CheckLength(string value)
{
    return value.Length >= 4;    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the compound code to code-behind method. For example the

```
'<%# ((string)Eval("Phone")).Length == 4 %>'
```

becomes

```
'<%# IsPhoneSpanVisible( (string)Eval( "Phone" ) ) %>'
```

with

```
protected bool IsPhoneSpanVisible( string Phone )
{
   // provide your logic here
}
```

This way you'll be easily able to debug your code.