# ASP: Format number with Eval and 3 sections

Tags: asp.net, numbers, format, eval

I have a ListView with a label in which I put a number. Normal formatting would be something like this:

```
Text='<%# Eval("JustaNumber", "{0:#,##0.00}")%>
```

BUT...

I want a different formatting based on the value of 'JustaNumber'. I want to include the sign plus for positive numbers, minus for negative and nothing for zero.
I thought this would work with normal formatting with 3 sections format, but no, it does not. I get only the first format (always with a plus-sign).

```
Text='<%# Eval("JustaNumber", "{0:+ #,##0.00;(- #,##0.00);(#,##0.00)}")%>
```

I am overlooking something, maybe my knowledge is not sufficient, but I am stuck here...

Can someone please give me a hint where to look any further for a solution? Did a lot of searching on the internet, but answers are all with a 1 section format.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can create a method and use it in aspx page. Look at that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8069970/calling-a-property-or-member-function-of-a-string-object-inside-of-a-listview

Comment: Thanks, that would be a solution. However, the 3 section format is standard formatting syntax. Why does that not work with Eval?

Answer (score 0):

You can format your text any way you want with this approach. I usually go with this approach whenever my formatting moves beyond very simple formatting or computations. And yes, you can access `Eval()` within your method as long as it is invoked as part of a data binding operation.

This appears to work. `Eval()` may only support a subset of `string.Format` but I didn't test your original solution.

```
<asp:label runat="server" Text='<%# GetText()")%>

protected string GetText()
{
    return string.Format("0:+ #,##0.00;(- #,##0.00);(#,##0.00)",
        Eval("JustaNumber"));
}
```